# using the "this" keyword does not fetch the packagname to Startservice()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to start a service on android by using a intent in Xamarin forms, when the service is launched a Exception happens "Java.Lang.NullPointerException:", I think it is happening because the Package name is blank, the way I found this out is just assigning a var to the PackageName what always returns null. also in a standalone version app for android the PackageName appears before the "/md5" when using the "this" keyword.

I have gone into android manifest via the properties and checked if a package name exists.

I have gone into the androidmamifest.xml and checked if the package name exists

I have tried assigning a var to the package name just to see what is returned.

```
public void m_execute()
        {
            // found the issue, packagename value is null
            var pk_Name = PackageName;
            startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(TService));
            startServiceIntent.SetAction(Constants.ACTION_START_SERVICE);
            // null pointer exception when stepping into StartService
            StartService(startServiceIntent);
        }
```

Java.Lang.NullPointerException
  Message=Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ComponentName android.content.Context.startService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no `Context` in your class. The class needs to know where to start the service.

We can fix this by the plugin [CurrentActivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin).

Simply call the Init method on **OnCreate** in your `MainActivity` .

```
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
```

```
//...
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
//...
```

And you can totally do something like this:

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.StartService(startServiceIntent);
```